# extjs 3.4 use combo store to create checkbox group items

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm using Extjs 3.4. I already have a combo with a `JsonStore` that receives a `JsonDataReader` object from a Seam Component's method.

I want to use this store values to create checkbox items and after that a checkbox group with these items. It would be nice if I had a solution to do that and not to be in need of rewrite the whole js file.

Comment: So you want to know if there's a way to just pass the records in the store and it will automatically create check boxs for the records in the store?

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox.store.each(function (record) {
    items.push({
        boxLabel: record.get(comboBox.displayField),
        name: record.get(comboBox.valueField)
    });
});
```

Demo here http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-3-use-combo-store-to-create-checkboxgroup-items